# Why cant Dollar symbol be used as an alternative fo jQuery in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Why can't we use "$" instead if jQuery in wordpress? Usually "$" is the alternative of jQuery right? But in Wordpress it shows **"$" is not a function**. I dont get why is that so. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at tip 5 in this web page: [5 Tips for using jquery with wordpress](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/):

> It is important to know that the version of jQuery that comes with
>   WordPress automatically calls the jQuery.noConflict(); function, which
>   gives control of the $ variable back to whichever library first
>   implemented it. If you are loading a different copy of jQuery, you'll
>   need to manually call jQuery.noConflict();, if necessary, from one of
>   your JavaScript files.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You can also do something like this:
`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('myobject').html();
}`

Answer (score 3):

> The tricky thing is this particular copy of jQuery is in compatibility
>   mode by default. That means that the typical ‘$’ shortcut for jQuery
>   doesn’t work, so it doesn’t conflict with any other JavaScript
>   libraries that use the dollar sign also, like MooTools or Prototype.

Source: [Using ‘$’ instead of ‘jQuery’ in WordPress](http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I found the mention of compatibility mode and the implication that perhaps a different version of jQuery would allow the $ shortcut to be used. Every post on this issue I have seen ends with somebody saying "Just replace $ in your script with 'jQuery'" ... what what if we want to use the shortcut? This seems to be the operable question in my mind. I've seen this apply to WordPress a lot, but my situation is CDN: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(...)` should be used instead of `$(...)`

Edit ----
sorry, i misread your question.
It depends on the jquery implementation of your wordpress version.
I have seen wordpress sites that allowed the usage of `$` before, but i don't really know what it depends on.