# Woocommerce update checkout ajax

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

As i'm using a onepager for 1 product i'd like to make use of wordpress ajax to update the checkout on site, when i'm adding the product to the cart. The product add to cart button is already ajax.

I have tried the: `$('body').trigger('update_checkout');`, but it didnt work. It's inside an .on click function. I suspect that the checkout updater runs before the add to cart can get to save and therefore doesn't have anything to read from. This is just a theory though.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 16):

This works:

```
jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

You can not use dollar sign `$` to call jQuery in wordpress, instead you must use the string `jQuery`

Have a look at tip 5 in this web page: 5 Tips for using jquery with wordpress:

> It is important to know that the version of jQuery that comes with
> WordPress automatically calls the jQuery.noConflict(); function, which
> gives control of the $ variable back to whichever library first
> implemented it. If you are loading a different copy of jQuery, you'll
> need to manually call jQuery.noConflict();, if necessary, from one of
> your JavaScript files.

The explanation is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132734/3471458

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following trigger instead.

```
$( document ).trigger( 'wc_update_cart' );
```

Best regards

Comment: This solution used to work but is probably deprecated now since 3.x or newer.

Comment: This solution is working but is not for checkout, it's used to update cart only.

Comment: This works well to update cart page fragments. I've been looking for this besides checkout page fragments update.