# update checkout after adding product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

am trying to do somthing like : [Woocommerce update checkout ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899318/woocommerce-update-checkout-ajax/70027154#70027154)! am building a multistep form for my client where the customer is adding a product in the cart using ajax . I need to update the checkout when a product is added into the cart . I tried to do an onclick function so when the user add the product in the cart the checkout step update without refreshing the page :

```
jQuery('#test').on('click',function(){
    $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
})
```

but its not working and i feel like am missing somthing obvious .... Any tips ? :)

Answer (score 3):

This event fire after checkout update

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() { 

    //Write code here to fire event 
    console.log('run');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct you have to replace $ with jQuery

```
 //Paste this code in theme footer.php file and check it on checkout page
<?php if (is_checkout()) { ?>
  <button id="test">Click here to update checkout</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#test').on('click',function(){ alert("pp");
        jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
      });
    });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

The code is tested everything is working fine.

Comment: thanks i managed to update the checkout with ajax but now i have an other problem  aha... it shows the chekout but it wont load the necessary stripe script to display the card field....

Comment: ok I have a solution check the next post


jQuery( document ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() { 

    //Write code here to fire event 
    console.log('');

});