# Delete Label from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want DELETE only from table class="variations" with javascript the label which has attribute for = 'pa_cb5feb1b7314637725a2e7'

```html
<table class="variations">
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7">Ships From</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_cb5feb1b7314637725a2e7">Color</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I WANT TO KEEP only "Ships From";
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Okay. And how are you going about attempting that?

Comment: Hi, please elaborate?

Comment: Help with what? What is your problem? There's plenty of resources on removing DOM elements, querying DOM structures and there's of course the mighty documentation online on Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Make a Script tag in the last and get all element with label tag and delete the element which has the same for attribute as you want. Here is the Code that might help -

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="variations">
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7">Ships From</label></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_cb5feb1b7314637725a2e7">Color</label></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   var labeltags = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
   for (var i=0;i<labeltags.length;i++){
       if (labeltags[i].getAttribute("for")=="pa_cb5feb1b7314637725a2e7"){
           labeltags[i].remove();
       }
   }
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to delete it only from a table that class : <table class = "variations">

Comment: Just get the Variations Class first and then query for all label tags in that particular class only. You just need to change two lines in the script tag -                                                          
    var variationsClass = document.getElementsByClassName("variations")[0];
    var labeltags = variationsClass.getElementsByTagName("label"); and then you can continue the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelector()` to select the element. If you have multiple elements, use `querySelectorAll()` and iterate over the resulting list. Then, you can remove it from the DOM with `remove()`. Here is an example:

```
var el = document.querySelector('label[for=pa_cb....]');
if (el) {
  el.remove();
}
```

---

If you want to keep the inner HTML and append it to the parent, you could store the it in a variable, remove the label and then add the inner HTML to the parent. Here is an example:

```
var el = document.querySelector('label[for=pa_cb....]');
if (el) {
  var innerHtml = el.innerHTML;
  var parentElement = el.parentElement;
  el.remove();
  parentElement.innerHTML += innerHtml;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but how to have it deleted only from a table that class : <table class = "variations">

Comment: @cham You can use a different selector: e.g. `table.variations label[for=pa_cb....]`

Answer (score 1):

As much I understand you need to remove the label by the for value.

Then this might help you.

Using Javascript

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll(".variations label[for]");
console.log(labels);

for(let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++ ) {
  if(labels[i].getAttribute('for') === 'pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7') {
    labels[i].remove();
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/oNbzNev)

One line solution in Jquery (life-saver)

```
$('.variations').find("label[for='pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7']").remove();
```

Comment: thanks for your help but how to have it deleted only from a table that class : <table class = "variations">

Comment: I have updated, please check the answer. If it helped then please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: You can go with a single line solution as well if you are using jQuery. Please have a look at the updated answer for jQuery Solution.

Comment: this code work with jQuery, so i will integrate it to my wordpress.

Comment: Yes, use the jQuery Solution it will work. You might need to replace `$` with `jQuery ` in Wordpress.

Comment: You don't need `jQuery` in 2020 anymore. Use `querySelector` instead. Especially not for selecting elements.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 you are right. It basically depends on which version of jquery you are using. For an older version, you need to use `jQuery`. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132734/9739044`